# ServiceSecurityContext missing in .Net Core (v3.0)

Tags: .net-core

I'm migrating a bunch of .Net Framework 4.6.1 projects into the new .Net Core 3.0 and can't find a nuget packaged that contains the ServiceSecurityContext class.

In .Net Framework the package is located on the System.ServiceModel. Is there a new class that does the same job? Any tips?

Comment: The System.Private.ServiceModel package only contains the System.Reflection.DispatchProxy, System.Security.Cryptographi.xml and System.Security.Principal.Windows, the ServiceSecurityContext is not there

Comment: Sounds like they do remove it from .NET Core, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.servicesecuritycontext?view=netframework-4.8#applies-to

Answer (score 0):

CoreWCF has ServiceSecurityContext implemented. 
https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF/blob/b8b33318273cb889bac60b7c8a4c18106e6eb808/src/CoreWCF.Primitives/src/CoreWCF/ServiceSecurityContext.cs

Although, you need to validate if this suites your specific requirements and whether it is interoperable with your .NET Core setup.